# Cannot GET the data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, backend

I'm trying to GET my data from MongoDB but it doesn't seem to work...

My code for the server.js file is: https://www.paste.org/111681

My code for the route I'm using in Insomnia to GET:  https://www.paste.org/111682

And this is what I get in Insomnia:

[image]

I have a very similar code in another project and it GETs the data from MongoDB just fine, I don't really know what is wrong in here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would help us if you show us your code?

Comment: Code is in the paste.org Links!

Comment: Please put formatted code directly into your question instead of providing external links.

Comment: I dont know how :(

Answer (score 1):

When you get a page saying `Cannot GET` that means that the route doesn't exist or you called the wrong method. You explicitly stated that you wanted to GET the data so the latter is ruled out. That means you probably have a typo. Did you mean `gbpbatting` as gbp is a real currency?

Comment: I meant gpbbatting -- gpb are the acronyms of a team. The file name containing the GET method is gpbbatting, the route is exported as gpbbatting in the server.js file too. I fail to see what is wrong. Halp

Answer (score 0):

You're making a call to `/gbpbatting` in Insomnia when your endpoint is `/add` in the code below:

```
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    ...
}
```

Change the GET request in Insomnia to `http://localhost:5000/add` or rename your endpoint to `/gbpbatting`.

Comment: Hey! I am using the root route ('/') as my GET 

The ('/add') route is a POST, it doesn't work either btw.

Comment: I tried changing the route to '/gpbbattings' and it isn't working